# Levi Civita product proof

Tags: kronecker-symbol

Does anyone know/know where to find the proof of:

$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmn} = +δ_{il}δ_{jm}δ_{kn} + δ_{im}δ_{jn}δ_{kl} + δ_{in}δ_{jl}δ_{km}
−δ_{im}δ_{jl}δ_{kn} − δ_{il}δ_{jn}δ_{km} − δ_{in}δ_{jm}δ_{kl}$$

Thank you much

Comment: Are you sure this equality is even right?

Comment: @MASL: It is a valid formula i think, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita-Symbol

Comment: @MrYouMath Thanks. It was also a reminder for Garbojax to show a bit more effort in finding an answer. Garbojax, it is convenient to show what you tried, were you searched and rather ask more specific question like were you are stuck. This usually gives rise to more interesting answers as well. Anyways, welcome to MSE.